# kendoui validation tooltip in custom popup editor not positioning correctly

Tags: kendo-ui

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delebash/t3Pz5/1/) for example, blank out First Name field to have validation tooltip show.  In a normal form the validation tooltip positions correctly to the right of each element.  But in the popup editor for the grid it still trying to position the tooltip below the element as if it where editing inline.  I have tried `<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="FirstName"></span>`but it doesn't change anything.  Is there a setting I am missing to get this working in popupeditor?  I guess I could manually modify the .k-tooltip but I am hoping for something more built in that handles the positioning correctly, because I am not very good at css.

Comment: You know it would be nice if who ever down voted this would explain why.  To me this is a valid question with a valid example demonstrating the problem.  I like kendoUI that is why I am using it but anyone who uses KendoUI knows the docs and example are very poor and I have spent hours debugging, forum searching ect to figure it out and it has been very counter productive

Comment: Well I found out the reason for the problem.  The built in grid validation errorTemplate is wrappped in a div  <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation" style="margin:0.5em"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span>#=message#<div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>.  Where when you just use a kendo.Validator it is just a span <span class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span> #=message#</span>.  I have tried to change e.sender.editable.options.errorTemplate but it still uses the div.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've discovered, the error template for the grid is different to that provided by the kendo validator when applied to standard inputs.

Unfortunately, the validator that is created internally by the grid does not pass along any errorTemplate that you might define in the options object and by the time the "edit" event fires, the validator has already been created and the error template compiled, hence why setting the errorTemplate in the manner you describe does not work. Really, I think the Kendo grid should respect any user defined errorTemplate option but until it does we have to hack a little bit.

The key is to define a custom template and to apply it in the edit event, but instead of using the options object, set the private instance directly. Not ideal, but it works:

```
edit: function (e) {
    e.sender.editable.validatable._errorTemplate = 
         kendo.template($('#tooltip-template').html());
}
```

See this updated fiddle for an example of what I think you might be looking to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/nukefusion/eQ2j7/10/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working when using kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC, at least not in my case. It leads to a jquery error message:
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <span class = "k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" > <span class = "k-icon k-warning" > </span>Name is required.</span> (jquery-1.9.1.js, line 4421). Since I don't know anything about what is going on in jquery maybe someone else can enlighten me.

Comment: hi nukefusion, I have same type of problem but in JSP.can you please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085870/how-to-open-a-jsp-page-in-popup-editor-using-kendo-ui

Answer (score 2):

(I would post this as a comment but not enough reputation yet...)

I'm successfully using nukefusion's solution. I, too, fought with the syntax error from jQuery for a long time and discovered through debugging that *how* you define the template is important. In particular, it appears that the template has to be written on a single line without any formatting, as in:

```
<script id="tooltip-template" type="text/x-kendo-template"><span class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation"><span class="k-icon k-warning"></span>#=message#</span></script>
```

If you try to make it "pretty" and format the html in the template, you get the syntax error. I don't know where the real bug is, as this sort of thing shouldn't cause an error. But it does and I stopped worrying about it once I got it to work correctly.