# how to open a JSP page in popup editor using kendo UI

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, popup, kendo-grid

I am using **Kendo-UI with JSP-wrapper** (`<kendo:grid>`) . I have two JSP pages `Employee.jsp` & `EmployeeDetails.jsp`.the sample code for employeeDetails.jsp is given on [Kendo Grid using JSP wrapper](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/editing-popup) EmployeeDetails has a grid with editable_mode =popup.which is working fine.But since in Employee.jsp we have a lots of data so the popup window is very large and hard to maintain.

the output what i wanted is the popup should comes in two row with custom style sheet instead of default one row and Keno Style-sheet.

the similar functionality is achieved in   [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/BCBzS/1/) but he is using **html/js** , not jsp wrapper.and other problem is that he is writing the entire html code of popup in the same html page which i don't want.

**[EDIT:]** I find an entry point to proceed further using [kendo:grid-editable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/editable).the sample code may be

```
<kendo:grid>
    ..............
    ..............
    <kendo:grid-editable mode="popup">
        <kendo:grid-editable-template>
            "<h1>Deepak</h1>"
        </kendo:grid-editable-template>
    </kendo:grid-editable>
    </kendo:grid>
```

but another problem still remains that we need to provide all html code between

```
 <kendo:grid-editable-template>"....."</kendo:grid-editable-template>
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: may be template attribute of <kendo:grid-editable> would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same for the time being and its working for me of course.

```
     .................
        .................
            <kendo:grid>
                ..............
                ..............
                <kendo:grid-editable mode="popup">
                    <kendo:grid-editable-template>
                        +"<label for='FirstName'>First Name*:</label></td><td><input type='text' class='k-textbox' name='firstName' id='FirstName' required='required' /></td>"
                                +"<td> <label for='LastName'>Last Name*:</label></td><td><input type='text' class='k-textbox' name='lastName' id='LastName' required='required' /></td></tr>"
                                +"<tr><td><label for='EmpId'>Emp ID*:</label></td><td><input type='text' class='k-textbox' name='empid' id='id' required='required' /></td>"
                                  + "........................."
                                  + "........................."

                    </kendo:grid-editable-template>
                </kendo:grid-editable>
                </kendo:grid>
.....................................................
.....................................................
```

You need to keep two point in your mind

1. The code between  `<kendo:grid-editable-template>  </kendo:grid-editable-template>` is treated as a single String so replace all of your **" "** in custom popup code with **' '** .for example use `<input type='text'...>` instead of `<input type="text"....>`.
2. To bind the value of grid data and popup data the name attribute should be same in both places.